# AlarmManager setTimeZone not working from API 26?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I would like to change the system timezone. I found AlarmManager has method setTimeZone. And it's still working in Nougat(Android7 API 24 25). But from 26 It always crash and shows that:

> UncaughtException: java.lang.SecurityException: setTimeZone: Neither user 10079 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE.

Can you guys give me some advice about this situation? Ah yes. My device is **rooted**.

In the manifest, I have request permission already.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
```

Thank you very much for your read.

Comment: For some permissions, you have to explicitly ask user in the runtime: [link](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: @echosoftware I asked. But I denied. Thank you very much.